# Image displayed using jQuery not shown on Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-scroll

I have an image called 'loader.gif'. I am providing one Ajax call in my application. Before giving the Ajax call I am displaying this image to the user so that he knows that some process is running in background. After the Ajax response is received and rendered I am hiding that image.

```
<div id="virtualScrollSpinner" class="infinite-loading" style="display:none">
  <img src="<s:property value="staticResourcesURL"/>/img/common/icons/loader.gif" alt="Loader" />
</div>
```

Mentioned above is the image tag that I have in my JSP. I am using the following jQuery lines to hide/show this.

```
$('div#virtualScrollSpinner').show();
$('div#virtualScrollSpinner').hide();
```

Somehow this image just does not appear in Chrome and IR browser.

Comment: http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/Simple-Struts-2-0-x-tag-question-lt-img-src-quot-lt-s-property-value-item-imageURL-quot-gt-quot-gt-td3469046.html this may help u

Comment: How much time its taking to receive response, give some delay in hiding the image and check

Comment: Response is relatively fast. But still I am able to see the image in Firefox browser. When I apply a delay I am able to see it in Chrome and IE.

Comment: Can one of you look into my other issue too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049088/page-clicks-not-working-during-virtual-scroll

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the div is where you expect it to do (x,y) and well as checking its z-order.  I am assuming that it appears in other browsers apart from chrome and IE - right.

Use Firebug to check.

Comment: As you said I checked in using Firebug. Image div is exactly where I expect it to be. It appears on all browsers except IE and Chrome. Does this two browser take some extra time for rendering the image?

Comment: Hmm, maybe don't do the hide and see if it appears.  Also check with F12 on IE

Comment: If I do not hide the image, I am able to see it. But I do not intent on displaying it always. It is normally hidden and shown as an indication to user that server is processing his response.

Comment: Can one of you look into my other issue too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049088/page-clicks-not-working-during-virtual-scroll